# Is it possible to do a navigation bar with drop down links without javascript?

Tags: html, css, menu

Is it possible to do a navigation bar in [this style](http://dev.visualdrugs.net/mootools/dropdown_menu.html) without JavaScript?

I assumed it would be possible using CSS with `:hover` changing the visibility of the list, but I haven't been able to find examples like this.

Comment: Seriously? You couldn't find a tutorial for CSS-drop-down? I'd suggest looking at Stu Nicholl's ['CSS Play' website, for *lots* of menu ideas](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/).

Comment: You can do it with only css, but it is a lot easier with js/jq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're asking because you're not sure what to Google (i.e. you don't know what terminology to use to find what you're looking for).

I suggestion Googling `pure CSS drop down menu`. You'll find lots of great tutorials and code samples. Here's a decent one:

http://purecssmenu.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can write like this:

```
#dropdownMenu li > ul{
    display:none;
}
#dropdownMenu > li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/VceX4/1/

Comment: +1 I tried to include only angular.js and leave out bootstrap.js and jquery.js references. But I still wanted to use bootstrap styling and markup. This worked really well for that.